# The dreadful lunch

Tags: number-theory

> There are $100$ cakes for lunch at $1$pm. One of them is poisoned. The poison takes exactly $1$ hour to kill the person who ate it. But still, some people have to taste it (just through a small piece) to make sure the lunch can be held safely. It is now $11$:$30$am. What is the minimum amount of people that have to risk their lives?

I have no idea what the answer is. Someone can eat multiple cakes so I know the answer is not 100.

By the way, can someone change the tags? I actually don't know what tag(s) it belongs to.

Comment: Like I said, I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Try answering the question for 1 cake, then 2 cakes, 3 cakes, etc. as a start.

Comment: 1 cake 1 person 2 cake 2 persons 3 cake 2 persons...

Comment: Well here we have two different types of people: "Alive" people and "Posioned (Dead)" People. Can we make a ratio between the alive and the dead? This is not a hint, this is just a comment, sort of like adding to the discussion, because I too don't know how to answer this problem.

Comment: Your answer for 2 cakes is incorrect.

Comment: Well yes 2 cakes 1 person

Comment: So write 100 in binary and 2^7>100, so the answer is 7?